# Stampit - TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, stampit.js

autor.js:

```
var stampit = require('./stampit');
    var Autor = function () {
    var objetoAutor = stampit();   
    var Clase = function() { 
        var nombreCompleto ='';
        var fechaNacimiento ='';
        var nacionalidad ='';
        function constructor(nombreCompleto,fechaNacimiento,nacionalidad){
           nombreCompleto=nombreCompleto;
           fechaNacimiento=fechaNacimiento;
           nacionalidad=nacionalidad; 
        };

        this.getNombreCompleto = function () {
            return nombreCompleto;
        };

        this.getFechaNacimiento = function () {
             return fechaNacimiento;         
        };
        this.getNacionalidad = function () {
             return nacionalidad;
        };

        this.setNombreCompleto = function(nombreCompleto){
             nombreCompleto=nombreCompleto;
        };
        this.setFechaNacimiento = function (fecha){
            fechaNacimiento=fecha;
        };
        this.setNacionalidad = function (nacionalidad) {
            nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
        }; 

    };
    objetoAutor.init(Clase);
    return objetoAutor.create();
    };
    module.exports = Autor;
```

controlador.js:

```
var Autor = require('./autor.js');
var assert = require('assert');
var autor = Autor();
autor.setAutor('Ismael');
autor.setFechaNacimiento('04/07/1983');
autor.setNacionalidad('Española');
it ('Correcto el nombre del autor',function(){
  assert.equal(autor.getNombreCompleto(),'Ismael');
  assert.equal(autor.getFechaNacimiento(),'04/07/1983');
  assert.equal(autor.getNacionalidad(),'Española');
});
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\javie\Desktop\paginasWeb\Angular\NodeJS\JavaScript>node controlador.js
C:\Users\javie\Desktop\paginasWeb\Angular\NodeJS\JavaScript\controlador.js:4
autor.setAutor('Ismael');
      ^

TypeError: autor.setAutor is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\javie\Desktop\paginasWeb\Angular\NodeJS\JavaScript\controlador.js:4:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I am working with nodeJS creating an encapsulated and lightweight object, when I run controller.js I get the above error, I tried to change objetoAutor.init (Class) or objetoAutor.compose (Class) but I still have the same error, objectAuthor. enclose (Class) does not work for me, I have installed the following packages:
npm install -g mocha
npm install -g require
npm install stampit

Answer (score 0):

The error says something like: "setAutor can not be found". I can't find the function `setAutor` in your `autor.js`. Thus, it can't be called.

I'm no sure where you got those stampit examples, but that code won't work any way. You might want to check this website for more stampit examples: https://stampit.js.org

I'm the stampit's maintainer.

PS: you don't need to install `require` in node.js. It's a built-in thing.